# Android/Kotlin databinding error during runtime

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-databinding

When you use a included layout

`<include
    android:id="@+id/included"
    layout="@layout/content_fft"/>`

and use

`mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_record)`

I see this
[image]

but it **builds and runs properly**.

Does anyone has a clue how to get rid of it. It's very annoying because Android Studio shows me a lot of errors.

To demonstrate the error, I made a demo repo https://github.com/hannesa2/AndroidBinding3.2

Comment: I made a issue at Google for this too https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80029759

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of mBinding is wrong, it should be ActivityRecordBinding.

```
private lateinit var mBinding: ActivityRecordBinding
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just **be sure** if your layout file name is in **snake_case** then your
> binding class name would be in **CamelCase**.

### For example

Layout Name is **`activity_main.xml`**

Binding class name would be **`ActivityMainBinding.class`**

So your binding class name will be `ActivityRecordBinding`.